# Creating a non mapped property in an entity (entity framework)

Tags: entity-framework

I want to create a custom property on one of my entities mapped from the database, however this property is not mapped to the database, I created the property using partial classes but when trying to compile I get an error telling me that the property is not mapped. Is there an attribute or something I should add? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using partial classes is the correct way to do this, and works fine for me. You need to show your code, your mappings, and the exact error, as what you've described thus far already works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use partial classes to add the properties or methods you want added. E.g.

```
namespace WhateverNamespaceYourEntityModelIsIn
{
    public partial class  TheNameOfYourEntity
    {
          public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and that should do you.

Comment: For Code First, see Kniganapolke's answer specifically. Use [NotMapped].

Answer (score 132):

You can also mark your property with `[NotMapped]` attribute or use `Ignore` method from fluent API.

**Property**

```
public class EntityName
{
    [NotMapped]
    private string PropertyName { get; }
}
```

**Fluent API**

```
 public class Entities : DbContext
 {
    public DbSet<EntityType> Users { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // Some database configuration
       modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>()
             .Ignore(i => i.PropertyName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: this is a good solution when you want to add properties to the entity object but don't want them associated with the database or Mapping file

Comment: Using the [NotMapped] attribute is the easiest way to go if you have a property you need on all entites such as EntityState that you declare on a base class.  No need to edit every configuration class and remember to do so every time a new entity is introduced.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But when I try it, i get : "Does not support untyped value in non-open type." 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Toodoo, the error seems to be related to OData not to EF.

Comment: Because it was written years later after the OP stopped caring about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This page really helped me.  I'll add exactly what I added to my mapping configuration after seeing Kniganapolke's answer.

```
 public TheObjectName()
   {
       this.HasKey(t => t.ID);
       this.Ignore(t => t.IsProcess); //we don't want EF to worry about this
    }
```

Thanks everyone, thanks SO!

Answer (score 1):

I'm seriously late to the conversation, but you also want to mark the partial as serializable and the property as serializable - if you ever plan to JSON or serialize the objects:

```
[Serializable()] 
public partial class MyClass {
    private System.Nullable<int> _Age;
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(Order = 4)] 
    public System.Nullable<int> Age {
            ...
    }
}
```

Both the [Serializable()] and the [global:] directives are needed.   If you excluded the [global:], any time you serialized it, it'd be ignored and not included in the serialization.

Comment: Excellent! I was spinning my wheels for so long trying to figure out why only one of my posted variables was always null. This did the trick! Thanks!