# retrieving database-computed properties of classes within entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a good understanding of EF, and generated my database successfully. Now, I am struggling with adding dynamic properties to one of the entity classes. For example, I have a `Post` class, and other users can make comments to the posts. When I list the existing posts, I want to display the number of comments made to corresponding post.

One solution might be having a property called `CommentCount`, and updating the Post by increasing the (`int`) value of the `CommentCount` property by 1 when a new comment is made.

The other solution, and I think it is a better solution, is that when retrieving the post from the DB, the number of comments associated with the post can be computed and retrieved at the same time and assigned to `CommentCount` property of the post instance. However, I do not know how to achieve this with EF.

Which approach is highly recommended? Or, is there any other ways of doing this? If it is the second one, how can I achieve this with EF?

Comment: Are you using code-first?

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987836/creating-a-non-mapped-property-in-an-entity-entity-framework

Comment: my question is about how to bind data to `CommentCount`, how should I change `Post` class so that when I retrieve the `DBSet<Post> Posts`, each `Post` instance will have the correct `CommentCount` value?

Comment: It is not good practice to count comments each time, I would suggest a field inside Post table with CommentCount, which should be updated whenever comment was added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should simply consider **not putting** the property called `CommentCount` into your model. When you develop for example a WPF Windows application, you should consider using [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and the `CommentCount` would belong to your *ViewModel* class and not to your *Model* class. There you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you can use it from your frontend *Views*. Analogically there is MVC pattern for ASP.NET etc.

There are other design patterns like [Repository pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx). Using this pattern you can create the `CommentCount` in your repository class and not in your 
model class. This would be similar to your second solution.

2) I assume from your question that you are using code-first approach:

> generated my database successfully

If you do so and you wish to include `CommentCount` directly in your *Model* class, you can do it this by adding partial class file to your project like this:

```
namespace DBModel.Models
{
    public partial class Post
    {
        public int CommentsCount
        {
            get { return this.Comments.Count; }
        }
        ...
```

But I cannot see why to create extra property in your model just for that.

On the other hand adding this field as a computed field into your SQL database could make sense and then it would be part of your EF model.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculation is very complex you should try creating a View in your DB and then add it to your Model?

But if your Model have something simple like

```
class Post {
    public int postid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<comment> comment { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you can do

```
db.post(x => x.postid == yourid).comments.count()
```

to get total of comment

or  in your view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>item.postid;</li>
    <li>item.comment.Count();</li>
}
```

**Or update your class**

```
class Post {
    public int postid { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<comment> comment { get; set; }
    public int CommentCount
    {
        get 
        { 
            return comment.Count();
        }
    }

}
```

Just remember bring related data in your query.
In my case POI have properties `parish_id, sector_id, city_id` and parish have municipality, and municipality have state.

Using this query I can get Poi with all the related data.

```
filter = db.poi
           .Include("parish")
           .Include("sector")
           .Include("city")
           .Include("parish.municipality")
           .Include("parish.municipality.state")
           .Where(x => x.sector_id == SectorID);
```

Comment: Considering that it will be a complex calculation, my question is about how to bind data to `CommentCount`, how should I change `Post` class so that when I retrieve the `DBSet<Post> Posts`, each `Post` instance will have the correct `CommentCount` value?

Comment: @erkaner I update my comment, adding a property to the class. Take note if you want to change the class you need do it in a different derived class, Otherwise you lose the code if do an EF update from DB. Let me know if that works for you. Also will help if you show the code of your class.

Comment: @erkaner i also add a example of eager loading. Using `Include` will bring the relationed data.