# Return stored procedure data as table set

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using .net with entity framework database first approeach. I was wondering if it's possible for stored procedure to return result as table set instead of procedure result set.

Suppose I have a table:

```
table MyTable(
id int, 
value nvarchar(max))
```

And stored procedure:

```
procedure GetMyTableSet
AS
  Select *
  From MyTable A
  Where A.Value = 'test'
```

Now the type that the procedure returns in .net will be `GetMyTableSet_Result`, but is it possible for it to be `MyTable` because it has the same data structure? Can I cast it in procedure somehow or do something else?

EDIT: In .net my procedure is generated like this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<GetMyTableSet_Result> GetMyTableSet(string accessRight, Nullable<int> companyId, string accessParam, Nullable<bool> multipleCompanies)
        {
            var accessRightParameter = accessRight != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("accessRight", accessRight) :
                new ObjectParameter("accessRight", typeof(string));

            var companyIdParameter = companyId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("companyId", companyId) :
                new ObjectParameter("companyId", typeof(int));

            var accessParamParameter = accessParam != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("accessParam", accessParam) :
                new ObjectParameter("accessParam", typeof(string));

            var multipleCompaniesParameter = multipleCompanies.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("multipleCompanies", multipleCompanies) :
                new ObjectParameter("multipleCompanies", typeof(bool));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetMyTableSet_Result>("GetMyTableSet", accessRightParameter, companyIdParameter, accessParamParameter, multipleCompaniesParameter);
        }
```

What I wanted to know if it's possible for it to be like `ObjectResult<MyTable>` instead of `ObjectResult<GetMyTableSet_Result>` as the procedure returns the same data structure as it is for MyTable table.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an entity which can be stored in an object having any name you like. You could also use a `VIEW` rather than a stored procedure.

In code terms and using EF contexts:

```
MyEntity dbEntity = new MyEntity();
var MyTable = dbEntity.GetMyTableSet;
```

EF will do the mapping of data types so the returned object will mirror the types returned by the stored procedure (unless you use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to change the column type.

Comment: What I gave as an example was just to show what I need to do, which is - use stored procedure. The real procedure is more complex and I could not use view there. And I am not talking about entity name, but type. I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: @John I've modified the answer, I'm unclear as to what you're actual problem is. Do you have sample C#, EF code showing the problem?

Comment: I edited my post, hope it's more clearer now. But the more I think about it the more it seems like I am asking for something impossible / incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-6-code-first) to understand how to call procedures from Entity Framework. EF will do all the mappings between result set column values and properties based on column name, but you must take care of data type compatibility.

Also, I think you can control the mappings by specifying that some properties [should not be mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987836/creating-a-non-mapped-property-in-an-entity-entity-framework).